# Collision Detection, Player with tiles of the map

Tags: xna, monogame

How do I to make a collision with a tile from the map with my player?

Animation class:

```
public class Animation
{

    public float speed = 2.5f;
    protected string currentAnimatie;

    public Texture2D sTexture;
    public Vector2 sPosition;

    private int FrameIndex; 
    private double TimeElapse;
    private double TimeToUpdate;

    public Vector2 sDirection = Vector2.Zero;


    public Rectangle BoxRondCharachter
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)sPosition.X, (int)sPosition.Y, 50, 41);
        }
    }

    public int FramesPerSec
    {
        set { TimeToUpdate = (1f / value); }
    }

    public Animation(Vector2 pos)
    {
        sPosition = pos;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        TimeElapse += gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (TimeElapse > TimeToUpdate)
        {
            TimeElapse -= TimeToUpdate;

            if (FrameIndex < sAnimatie[currentAnimatie].Length - 1)
            {
                FrameIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                FrameIndex = 0;
            }
            TimeElapse = 0;
        }

        sPosition += sDirection;
        sDirection = Vector2.Zero;
    }

    public void AddAnimatie(int frames, double yPos, int xStart, string naam, int width, int height, Vector2 offset)
    {

        Rectangle[] Rectangles = new Rectangle[frames];

        ///neemt de spritesheet en het verdeelt zich
        for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
        {
            Rectangles[i] = new Rectangle((i + xStart) * width, (int)yPos, width, height);
        }

        sAnimatie.Add(naam, Rectangles);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sprite)
    {
        sprite.Draw(sTexture, sPosition, sAnimatie[currentAnimatie [FrameIndex], Color.White);
    }

    public void AnimatieAfspelen(string animatieNaam)
    {
        if (currentAnimatie != animatieNaam)
        {
            currentAnimatie = animatieNaam;
            FrameIndex = 0;

        }
    }

    public void LaadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        sTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>("char");
    }
}
```

MapEngine Class:

```
class MapEngine
{
    private List<CollisionTiles> collisionTiles = new List<CollisionTiles>();

    public List<CollisionTiles> CollisionTiles
    {
        get { return collisionTiles; }
    }

    private int width, height;
    public int Width
    {
        get { return width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return height; }
    }

    public MapEngine()
    {

    }


    public void Generate(int[,] map, int size)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                int number = map[y, x];

                if (number > 0)
                {
                    collisionTiles.Add(new CollisionTiles(number, new Rectangle(x * size, y * size, size, size)));

                    width = (x + 1) * size;
                    height = (y + 1) * size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (CollisionTiles tile in collisionTiles)
        {
            tile.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Map class:

```
class Map : MapEngine
{

    public void ShowMap(ContentManager Content)
    {
        Tiles.Content = Content;

        Generate(new int[,]{
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,},
            {2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,},
            {2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,},
            {2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,2,2,},
            {2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,},
            {2,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,},
            {2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,}
        }, 74);
    }
}
```

Hero class:

```
public class Hero
{
    private Vector2 position = new Vector2(54, 485);
    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
    }

    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    private Animation _animation;
    private Inputs inputH = new Inputs();

    public bool LinkseStand = false;

    private Rectangle collisionRectangle;
    public Rectangle CollisionRectangle
    {
        get => collisionRectangle;
        set => collisionRectangle = value;
    }


    public Hero()
    {
        _animation = new Animation(position);

        _animation.AddAnimatie(4, 0, 0, "RechteIdle", 50, 35, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(4, 34, 0, "LinkseIdle", 50, 35, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(6, 72, 0, "Right", 50, 34, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(6, 107, 0, "Left", 50, 40, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(9, 144, 0, "Jump", 46, 41, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(4, 220, 0, "Crouch", 50, 32, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(7, 255, 0, "FirstAttack", 50, 45, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(14, 300, 0, "ComboAttack", 50, 41, new Vector2(0, 0));
        _animation.AddAnimatie(5, 300, 0, "Dood", 50, 41, new Vector2(0, 0));

        _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("RechteIdle");

        _animation.FramesPerSec = 8;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        _animation.Draw(spritebatch);
    }

    public void laadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        _animation.LaadContent(content);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        _animation.Update(gameTime);

        position += _animation.sDirection;
        CollisionRectangle = new Rectangle((int)_animation.sPosition.X, (int)_animation.sPosition.Y, 50, 41);


        inputH.update();
        Move(gameTime);

    }

    private void Move(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (inputH.Right)
        {
            _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("Right");
            _animation.sDirection.X = _animation.speed;

            LinkseStand = false;
        }
        else if (inputH.Left)
        {
            _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("Left");
            _animation.sDirection.X -= _animation.speed;

            LinkseStand = true;
        }
        else if (inputH.Up)
        {
            _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("Jump");

            _animation.sDirection.Y -= _animation.speed;
        }
        else if (inputH.NormalAttack)
        {
            _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("FirstAttack");
        }
        else if (inputH.ComboAttack)
        {
            _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("ComboAttack");
        }
        else
        {
            if (LinkseStand == true)
                _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("LinkseIdle");
            else
                _animation.AnimatieAfspelen("RechteIdle");
        }
    }
}
```

Collision tile class:

```
class CollisionTiles : Tiles
{
    public CollisionTiles(int i, Rectangle newRect)
    {
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tile" + i); //loads the tile (tile1, tile2)
        Rectangle = newRect;
    }
}
```

Game1 class:

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D background;
    Vector2 backPos;

    Animation _ani;
    Hero _hero;

    Map map;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1000;  // set this value to the desired width of your window
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 590;   // set this value to the desired height of your window
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        map = new Map();
        _hero = new Hero();
        _ani = new Animation(_hero.Position);
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background1");
        backPos = new Vector2(0, 0);

        map.ShowMap(Content);

            //_heroTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("idleStand");
            _hero.laadContent(Content);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// game-specific content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        _hero.Update(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Cyan);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(background, backPos, Color.White);

        map.Draw(spriteBatch);
        _hero.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `Tiles` class for completeness. More specifically does it directly expose the member `Rectangle` publicly or is that private/internal/protected and exposed in a property of another name?(I have already answered and pointed out where the changes(Rectangle->???) need to be made)

Comment: What is your anticipated result of a collision? My guess is that you would change the animation and use a stopped or collided version of the animation. As my answer provides, the Animation continues without moving(rolled back position) after it hits an object.

Comment: public Texture2D texture;

public Rectangle rectangle;

public Rectangle Rectangle
{
        get { return rectangle; }
        protected set { rectangle = value; }
}

public static ContentManager content;
public static ContentManager Content
{
        protected get { return content; }
        set { content = value; }
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);
}

Comment: Tile Class here becaus i cant put in the post  that i made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the Map instance to the Hero in the Update method in Game1:

```
    _hero.Update(gameTime, map);
```

And use that to loop through the `map.CollisionTiles` list checking for overlaps in the Hero class:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Map map)
{
    _animation.Update(gameTime);

    position += _animation.sDirection;
    CollisionRectangle = new Rectangle((int)_animation.sPosition.X, (int)_animation.sPosition.Y, 50, 41);

    // Check for collision with any of the CollisionTiles:
    foreach(var item in map.CollisionTiles)
        if(item.Rectangle.Intersects(CollisionRectangle))
//              ^^^^^^^^^ needs to be public in the tile class.
        {
            position -= _animation.sDirection; // Collided with a tile undo move
            break;    //prevent moving backwards if colliding with more than one tile
        }

    inputH.update();
    Move(gameTime);

}
```

In this code, the Hero is prevented from moving onto any CollisionTile.

Comment: i did this but stil going thru the tiles

Comment: i still appreciate your help

Comment: oke @Strom so i did this with Debug.writeLine, if hit with the right side, left side or top of the tile it wil show in the debug, and this works with your code, so this works i now only have to find put how to stop the player movement if he hits it